# Google Workspace Service Account Credential setup for automated sending of emails and calendar automation with the .NET API Library

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a Google Workspace with a few users in the directory, including a couple of Super Admins and regular users.  I have set up a service account, created an API Client with Domain-wide Delegation.

In code, I have the following for setting up the credential:

```
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
                .FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "my-project-112233445566.json"))
                .CreateScoped("https://mail.google.com/")
                .CreateWithUser("account@mydomain.com");
```

Note that the email address in CreateWithUser is a regular user in the directory.  I have NOT set up Gmail Delegation for any users. I enabled Email Delegation in the Admin Console, but the section in the users Gmail Settings page has not appeared that would allow me to add a delegate. That shouldn't matter since I have done the Domain-wide Delegation, right?

After creating that credential above and trying to send a mail message, I receive the following error message:

`The service gmail has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Delegation denied for account@mydomain.com`

In addition to Domain-wide Delegation do I need to explicitly delegate authority to the service account on a per-user basis?  According to the documentation I don't.

If I DO need explicit email delegation, why have I not seen the "Grant access to your account" section on the Accounts page of the Gmail Settings?

## Service Account Setup

### Google Cloud => IAM & Admin => Service Accounts setting page

[image: Service Account Settings Page]

### Google Workspace => Security => API Controls => Domain-wide Delegation

[image: Domain-wide Delegation]

Is there something else that I need to do to make impersonation happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the answer here for visibility since it was resolved in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247398/discussion-between-codewarrior-and-giselle-valladares)

It seems that the issue was not in the impersonation but by changing the `userId="me"`.

We also created a new project, services account, key, and domain-wide delegation following the steps in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the service account to impersonate a user on your domain then it has to be granted permission by the admin to impersonate that user.

The impersonation then also needs to be set up in your code.

```
 var gsuiteUser = "xxx@yourdomain.com";

            var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
            {
                User = gsuiteUser,
                Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend, GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels }

            }.FromCertificate(certificate);
```

Comment: I agree with @DalmTo. You can also see an example of the impersonation process with C#  [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1238).

Comment: @DalmTo Would you have more information about granting permission for the impersonation?  How is that accomplished as I have not seen anything about it.

Comment: @GiselleValladares would you have any info about how an admin grants permission to impersonate a user?  I have added screenshots above of the Service Account page and Domain-wide Delegation settings pages.  What other things do I need to allow impersonation?

Comment: You will need to do a [Domain Wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) in the Admin console of Google with the scopes that you are using in the Code. You need to do the [impersonation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1238) in the code with the email address of the user that will be use to send the emails.

Comment: @GiselleValladares I have done the Domain-wide Delegation (see the second image above).  Does the impersonation ONLY involve me using a users email address?  Do I need to make a setting change to explicitly allow a user to be impersonated by the service account?  In the above code, I am specifying an email address (changed for security reasons) that exists in my directory.  As a Super Admin, do I need to do something to allow the service account to impersonate the user OTHER than supplying that users email address to the credential creating method?

Comment: Just that, and make sure to download the JSON file from the services account since this will be the service account key. Like it mentioned in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount). That and the domain-wide delegation will be the only things that are required to impersonate any user inside of your domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247398/discussion-between-codewarrior-and-giselle-valladares).